# Java counter issue

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, io, counter

I am trying to write a program that reads values from a text file and checks how many values are within certain value ranges. The point is to eventually have the program print to the console the total number of values for each range. I have had it where it can do this 1 value at a time but then it would reset with every new int. In it's current it would simply repeat the first number over and over. To reiterate, I am trying to get it to report once it sorts through the values in the text file the amount of times a value was within the number ranges.

Here is my code.

```
package lab2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("lab2_input.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

        int counter1 = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;
        int counter3 = 0;
        int counter4 = 0;
        int counter5 = 0;
        int counter6 = 0;
        int counter7 = 0;
        int counter8 = 0;

        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {

            int number = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(number);

            if (number <= 24){
                counter1++;
            }
            if (25 <= number && number <= 49){
                counter2++;
            }
            if (50 <= number && number <= 74){
                counter3++;
            }
            if (75 <= number && number <= 99){
                counter4++;
            }
            if (100 <= number && number <= 124){
                counter5++;
            }
            if (125 <= number && number <= 149){
                counter6++;
            }
            if (150 <= number && number <= 174){
                counter7++;
            }
            if (175<= number && number >= 200){
                counter8++;
            }

        }

        System.out.println(counter1);
        System.out.println(counter2);
        System.out.println(counter3);
        System.out.println(counter4);
        System.out.println(counter5);
        System.out.println(counter6);
        System.out.println(counter7);
        System.out.println(counter8);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. LIke: include some sample input data, and show the output you get, and what you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to check for example range from 25 to 49, then instead of:

```
if (25 <= number && number <= 49){
    counter2++;
}
```

you should write:

```
if (25 >= number && number <= 49){
    counter2++;
}
```

Same thing about other checks.

P.S.: I  would suggest making `counter` an array and increment the elements based on calculated index, because the ranges are always 25: `var index = number / 25`.

Comment: Thank you! that is at least part of my problem.

Comment: @NickSims no problem, consider marking as correct if it helped

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a lot of manual `counter` keeping; your desired intervals are regularly separated at twenty-five, so I would use an array. Additionally, use `try-with-Resources` to avoid leaking file handles. And use `Scanner.hasNextInt()` with `Scanner.nextInt()` (not `Scanner.hasNextLine()`). Finally, I would add more descriptive messaging around the counts and their ranges. Like,

```
File file = new File("lab2_input.txt");
int[] counters = new int[9];
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        int v = scan.nextInt();
        if (v >= 0 && v <= 200) {
            counters[v / 25]++;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("The range %d to %d had %d values%n", i * 25, 
            ((i + 1) * 25) - 1, counters[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `else-if` blocks instead of multiple `if` blocks and get rid of the lower bound validation. This would make some performance improvement as well if you are dealing with a large list of numbers.

```
    if (number <= 24){
        counter1++;
    } else if (number <= 49){
        counter2++;
    } else if (number <= 74){
        counter3++;
    } else if (number <= 99){
        counter4++;
    } else if (number <= 124){
        counter5++;
    } else if (number <= 149){
        counter6++;
    } else if (number <= 174){
        counter7++;
    } else if (number <= 200){
        counter8++;
    }
```

Comment: Performance isn't really the first objective ... it is more about readability. I agree that this cascade reads much better ... but the big issue: normally you should put braces around **all** blocks. Then else if ... becomes else { if { } } ... and the required indenting leads to horrible nesting depth.

Comment: @GhostCat I think this is the exception to the "normally" in your statement for the very reason you give. I'd be surprised if any common set of style guides include a "surround `else if ` blocks in braces" requirement and expect the opposite actually.

Comment: @GhostCat I understand that in this case, this would not provide a significant performance improvement. But I personally don't agree with your statement that readability should be the the first objective than performance. Although readability is important for maintaining the code, performance should not be compromised for that. Because the primary goal of an application code is not to be read, but to be executed and perform some task efficiently.

Comment: @GhostCat And although `else if (condition)` provides the same behavior as  `if (condition) { } else { if (another_condition) {  }}`, they are 2 different syntaxes in Java. So there is no need to introduce additional braces or indentation to the above code.

Comment: *Because the primary goal of an application code is not to be read, but to be executed and perform some task efficiently.* For any significant piece of code, it will be read hundreds of times. It is only written once. If you get into premature optimisation, you end up with harder-to-read-and-understand code quickly. And that: will prevent you from coming in later and making changes, for example to improve performance. I agree, one shouldnt neglect performance. But, especially in java: performance rarely comes out of doing X or not doing Y in source code.

Comment: Performance comes out of the JIT doing its magic at runtime. And the JIT can work much better with simple straight forward code.